# Handle when text in a text box changes

Tags: jquery, text

I need to change text in a text box with jQuery, before onBlur and without using key events.

For example, if the text in the box was changed without the user typing any input, I could handle that event.

I've tried using `$('input.myInput').change()`, but the event only fires after the user tabs off of that text box.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: does the input box gain focus when this text is added?

Comment: I ended up just using setInterval(function() { //doStuff }, 100); to take care of this issue. It's working as I need it to.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: ew... ok... there's got to be a batter way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, there *isn't* and event for value/attribute change (called a [Mutation Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent)) built into jQuery.

There are [some plugins](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=mutation%20events%20in%20jquery&oq=mutation%20events%20in%20jquery&aq=f&aqi=g-j1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=31830l32102l0l32469l2l2l0l0l0l0l274l417l0.1.1l2l0) out there; however, YMMV with them.  I hope you find something that works for you!

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a while back, the best method i came up with is to bind other events that would change the value.

```
   $('input.myInput').bind('paste cut keyup mouseup change', function () {
           //Do Stuff
      });
```